# Woocommerce Table Rate Shipping plugin isn't calculating shipping rates correctly

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the [Table Rate Shipping plugin](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/table-rate-shipping/#section-7) and trying to set rates depending on the number of items in the cart. I have three different types of items (framed, mounted, prints) and I want the rates to apply to only the prints.

For example, I want to set it up so that:

If quantity is 1-3 prints, charge X…
If the quantity is 4-6 prints, charge 2X…
If the quantity is 7-9 prints, charge 3X…

Currently, this is how I have my settings, but the rates aren't being calculated correctly. If I put 3 items in my cart, it charges $72 when it should charge $24. For 4 items, it charges $192 when it should charge $48.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: try with "none" in the column "condition"

Comment: @Kaperto If I choose 'none,' then the min-max column gets greyed out.